# Why is natural transformation "reversed" in opposite category?

Tags: category-theory

I am studying a book of category theory. I felt confused when it says the morphism of $Fct(C_1,C_2)$, that is $\varphi: F\to G$ is reversed in $Fct(C_1^{op},C_2^{op})$, $\varphi^{op}:G^{op}\to F^{op}$. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: A morphism $F(c)\to G(c)$ in $C_2$ is a morphism $G(c)\to F(c)$ in $C_2^{op}$.

Comment: Ahh.. I see. Thank you!